# How do you perform multiple queries?

Tags: f#

I am trying to perform multiple subsequent queries based upon arguments in my function.  I can't quite figure out the syntax.

```
let returnVideoInfo catId isFeatured

    // main query
    let vidQuery = query{
        for row in db.Movies do
        where(row.IsFeatured = isFeatured)
        select row
    }    

    // I want to apply filters here based upon if arguments are null or not
    vidQuery
    |>
    (fun x -> 
    if catId <> null then
        Seq.filter (fun x -> x.CategoryId = catId) x
    else
    x)
```

This obviously doesn't work at all, so how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean after first pass read (could provide a dataset, format and expected return result), but would this work:

```
let returnVideoInfo catId (isFeatured : bool) = 
    let vidQuery = 
        match catId with
        | null -> ()
        | _ ->
            query{
                for row in db.Movies do
                where(row.IsFeatured = isFeatured && row.CatId = catId)
                select row
                exactlyOneOrDefault
            }
    vidQuery
```

or

```
let returnVideoInfo catId (isFeatured : bool) = 
    let vidQuery = 
        if catId <> null
            query{
                for row in db.Movies do
                where(row.IsFeatured = isFeatured && row.CatId = catId)
                select row
                exactlyOneOrDefault
        }
    vidQuery
```